# Keeping a duplicate row defined by item

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

**Problem:** Keeping only one row of duplicates (Date) defined by an Item.

Say you have this `DataFrame` with duplicate dates:

```
       Name    Item    Date        value1  value2
...
1235   Marc    A       21-Dec-17   7       1000
1236   Marc    H       05-Jan-18   9       2000
1237   Marc    Q       27-Jul-18   4       500
1238   John    H       14-Dec-17   4       500
1239   John    Q       07-Feb-18   6       500
1240   John    A       07-Feb-18   8       1000
1241   John    H       07-Feb-18   2       1000
1242   John    A       05-Dec-21   7       1000
1243   John    Q       27-Aug-25   8       500
1244   John    H       27-Aug-25   4       700
...
```

The unique values of col Item are `t = ['A', 'H', 'Q']`. The ranking by importance of t would be: A, Q and last H.

So e.g. rows 1239-1241 I would like to keep only row 1240 and for rows 1243-1244 I would like to keep only 1243.

I struggle to do this without a row-by-row iteration through the `dataframe`. And since the `dataframe` is huge I am looking for a faster solution. Is there an elegant way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
df['Item'] = pd.Categorical(df['Item'], categories= ['H','Q','A'], ordered=True)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df = df.sort_values(['Date','Item'], ascending=[True, False]).drop_duplicates('Date')
print (df)
      Name Item       Date  value1  value2
1238  John    H 2017-12-14       4     500
1235  Marc    A 2017-12-21       7    1000
1236  Marc    H 2018-01-05       9    2000
1240  John    A 2018-02-07       8    1000
1237  Marc    Q 2018-07-27       4     500
1242  John    A 2021-12-05       7    1000
1243  John    Q 2025-08-27       8     500
```

**Explanation**:

1. First convert `Item` column to [ordered categoricals](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html#categorical-data)
2. Convert dates by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html)
3. Sorting by [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by both columns and last [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

If want check duplicates by `Name` column:

```
df = df.sort_values(['Name','Item'], ascending=False).drop_duplicates('Name')
print (df)
      Name Item       Date  value1  value2
1236  Marc    H 2018-01-05       9    2000
1238  John    H 2017-12-14       4     500
```

And by `Name` and `Date`s:

```
df = df.sort_values(['Name','Date','Item'], ascending=False).drop_duplicates(['Name', 'Date'])
print (df)
      Name Item       Date  value1  value2
1237  Marc    Q 2018-07-27       4     500
1236  Marc    H 2018-01-05       9    2000
1235  Marc    A 2017-12-21       7    1000
1244  John    H 2025-08-27       4     700
1242  John    A 2021-12-05       7    1000
1241  John    H 2018-02-07       2    1000
1238  John    H 2017-12-14       4     500
```

Comment: But doesn't it then drop other rows as well, that have the same date?

Comment: @thedude - Yes, it drop all dupes `date`s, output are only unique `date`s.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't precise. It should only drop duplicates for the same Name